# How to safe delete (shred) a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, security

I want to store sensitive data in a MySQL database for a while, so I'd like to know a way to delete a MySQL database without having a chance of recovery. In Linux, we have a tool named [shred](https://linux.die.net/man/1/shred) which overwrites the content of the file repeatedly, so its content can never be recovered anymore. Problem is: I want to do it with a specific MySQL database. I know MySQL stores data in /var/lib/mysql, but there are several files there and it would destroy all databases and break MySQL. Any ideas?

Comment: shred is a an over-engineered "solution". `dd if=/dev/zero of=destfile` is sufficient as noone has proven recovery from a single overwrite. The layers below, like filesystem journal, ssd mapping, cloud storage are likely to be significantly harder problems to unravel. Suggest a block level encryption or a MySQL database level encryption.

Comment: As danblack says, don't focus adding more locks to your door while leaving the windows open.  As akuzminsky points out, there are a lot of windows.

Answer (score 2):

InnoDB leaves user data in several places.

1. `ibdata1` if `innodb_file_per_table=OFF` or respective *.ibd file if `innodb_file_per_table=ON`. This is where InnoDB stores the data.
2. `ib_logfile0` and `ib_logfile1` stores recent modifications.
3. Double write buffer (which resides in `ibdata1` no matter what `innodb_file_per_table` is) stores recent modifications.

To reliably delete user data you need to shred `ibdata1` - because of the double write buffer. If you do that, MySQL instance will be destroyed. So, I would say it's impossible to "shred" a particular database/table.

In your case I would create a replica with `mysqldump` (or `mydumper`, not with xtrabackup or a file system snapshot) and destroy the original instance/disk/server.